# How to fix black screen whenever a game starts?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, wine, screen

When I launch Minecraft, I log in, it updates, and then the screen turns black.

When I launch Counter-Strike, it launches, shows the Valve screen, and then the screen turns black.

I'm really pissed off because ive been trying non stop for two days looking through a bunch of bullshit that doesn't work. I'm on Ubuntu 12.04. I tried finding my Intel HD graphics family driver for Linux but Acer doesn't provide one. How might I fix this problem?

Comment: you shouldn't need drivers for intel hd drivers, if you want the name you can install

Comment: sudo apt-get install mesa-utils

Answer (score 3):

I know about Minecraft, but not Counter Strike, sorry. Download the minecraft.jar from [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftDownload/launcher/minecraft.jar). Put it on your Desktop. Right click and make a new document called "minecraft". Inside it, type this:

```
#!/bin/sh

java -Xms512M -Xmx512M -jar minecraft.jar nogui
```

Open your Terminal and do these following commands:

```
cd ~
cd Desktop
chmod a+x minecraft
```

The file called "minecraft" should be an executable, and open it up. Run it, and you should be able to play.

Answer (score 2):

Minecraft:
I know this is an old question but I had have a quite similar problem with minecraft.
The screen when it loads the files needed for minecraft appeared but after this there was only black.

I used suns java-7-jre.

Using the java-6-jre for playing minecraft fixed it for me.

Counter Strike:
I asume that you are using wine to play it. If you start it via steam you might add "-dxlevel 70" to the startoptions of CS(S).

This might help others.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding certain things. First, Counter Strike is not an Ubuntu application, instead it must be run through Wine, which is guarantee whatsoever that it will run. You can consult http://appdb.winehq.org for specific information, test results and how-tos that are relevant for your application.

Secondly, there is no need to look for graphics drivers, since Ubuntu already includes them, as they are part of the Linux kernel. The current state is as good as it gets.

Coming to a conclusion: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Well im mainly trying to get minecraft to work everytime i log in it will show the update screen for one second then just be black for the longest time i got java and all of that. do you know how to fix this?